# Ruby on Rails undefined method user_registration_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm getting an error:

```
NoMethodError in Devise/registrations#new
```

`undefined method 'user_registration_path'`

at this line:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

This is my routes:

```
  devise_for :user, :controllers => { :registrations => "devise/registrations" }, :skip => [:registrations, :sessions] do 
    # devise/registrations

    get 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration 
    post 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :custom_user_registration 
  end
```

Rake Routes:

```
      new_user_registration GET    /signup(.:format)      devise/registrations#new
   custom_user_registration POST   /signup(.:format)      devise/registrations#create
```

why am I getting the `user_registration_path` error?

Comment: output of rake routes?

Comment: @NicolasGarnil I updated my OP to show what i have for my signup page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running rake routes, do you see in output smth like this:

```
user_registration POST    /users(.:format)     devise/registrations#create
```

I think if you wrote this line

```
post 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :custom_user_registration
```

Now you have:

```
custom_user_registration POST    /signup(.:format)     devise/registrations#create
```

And should use `custom_user_registration_path(resource_name)` instead of `registration_path(resource_name)`

Comment: It also raise error undefined method 'custom_user_registration_path'?

Comment: actually, its a different error. I think because I have this: `<%= devise_error_messages! %>` and i'm getting undefined method 'errors'. If I delete that, then it works! But how do you do it so that error message works too?

Comment: Your error message like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219670/devise-error-messages-causes-undefined-method-errors-for-nilnilclass

Answer (score 1):

You are skipping the registrations routes and not overriding them all with the custom routes you've defined. Remove `:registrations` from the skipped routes. In your routes.rb:

This

```
devise_for :user, :controllers => { :registrations => "devise/registrations" }, :skip => [:registrations, :sessions] do
```

should be

```
devise_for :user, :controllers => { :registrations => "devise/registrations" }, :skip => [:sessions] do
```

Or you can add these custom routes if you want the path to always be /signup:

```
devise_for :user, :controllers => { :registrations => "devise/registrations" }, :skip => [:registrations, :sessions] do 
  get 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration 
  post 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#create', as => :user_registration
  delete 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#destroy', as => :destroy_user_registration
end
```

I don't advise changing the helper names (`as => :whatever`) since the devise controllers and views use them. It's fine to add new ones. I'm not sure you need to specify the controller either if it's the default.