# How to put a login form in the header for Devise and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to put a login form in the header of my website. I use Rails 3.2.8 and the latest Devise. In the `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` file a login form is created with:

```
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'main'}) do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.label :login %> <%= f.text_field :login, :placeholder => 'Enter username' %></div>
    <div><%= f.label :password %> <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => 'Enter password' %></div>
    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
    <% end -%>
    <%= f.submit "Go" %>
  <% end %>
```

If I try to copy that code and put it in my `application.html.erb`, I get an error regarding that resource variable referenced above:

```
undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<#<Class:0x3cb62c8>:0x3c73b00>
```

So can I just use a normal rails form with `/users/sign_in` as the action? How do I tell devise where to redirect to after logging in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We have a wiki page for that on the Devise wiki:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

Enjoy!

Comment: Perfect. How do I direct a user to a particular page afterwards?

Comment: I believe there is a wiki entry for that too. But in few words, you just need to override `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` in your ApplicationController.

Comment: yes, but then I wasn't able to easily see how to do the default action if I didn't specify the target page. For example, normally I click on a link that has the `before_filter :authenticate_user!` call in the controller, so it takes me to the login page first. I want a login to then take me to that originally requested page.

Comment: There is a page in the wiki for that too: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update

Answer (score 1):

You have to include `@user = User.new` in all the controller actions that will display the header with the login form.

For example, say you have a Pages controller with Home action. And you want to display the login form in the navigation of application layout.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @user = User.new
  end
end
```

On the application.html.haml, you'd have something like

```
- if user_signed_in?
  = link_to "sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
- else
  = form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'main'}) do |f| 
  ...
```