# How to test devise views with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I would like to test my registration view with rspec.

I have tried many things like suggested here [Testing devise views with rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426746/testing-devise-views-with-rspec)
or [Testing Views that use Devise with RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005444/testing-views-that-use-devise-with-rspec)

But nothing seems to be ok, I always get an error like:

```
undefined local variable or method `resource'
```

or

```
does not implement: resource
```

My current spec (spec/views/devise/registrations/new.slim_spec.rb):

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'devise/registrations/new.slim', type: :view do

  describe 'sign up form' do

    before do
      allow(view).to receive(:resource).and_return(User.new)
      allow(view).to receive(:resource_name).and_return(:user)
    end

    it 'does not contains an area for user avatar' do
      render
      expect(rendered).to_not include('Profile Pic')
    end
  end
end
```

my environment:

- rails 4.2.3
- devise 3.5.1
- rspec 3.3.0

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Edit:

I move my code to controller spec and it works, not perfect but...

```
RSpec.describe Users::RegistrationsController, type: :controller do
  before(:each) do
    request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  end

  describe '#new' do
    render_views

    it 'does not contains an area for user avatar' do
      get :new
      expect(response.body).to_not include('Profile Pic')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried the wiki page? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara

Comment: You should post some code to show what you have tried.

Comment: @ruby_newbie I've just added my spec.

Comment: the correct answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426746/testing-devise-views-with-rspec/

Answer (score 1):

## 1. set configuration in rails_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :view
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller

  # add these if you need other type of rspec.
  # config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :feature
  # config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
end
```

## 2. your view Rspec.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'rendering locals in a partial', type: :view do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  before :each do
    sign_in user
  end

  it "displays the widget" do
    widget = Widget.create!(:name => "slicer")

    render :partial => "widgets/widget.html.erb", :locals => {:widget => widget}

    expect(rendered).to match /slicer/
  end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Look into the Capybara gem. Here is a great guide to get you started (https://github.com/eliotsykes/rspec-rails-examples#capybara-examples).

He has devise examples as well, (https://github.com/eliotsykes/rspec-rails-examples/blob/master/spec/features/user_registers_spec.rb).

Comment: It seems you are recommending for the OP to move his code into a feature/integration test. This does not answer the question though if his objective was to unit test the view.