# I can't sign out from inside a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using devise and I'm struggling to log out from inside a partial.

```
<%= link_to "Bye", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

That's the code. I have exactly the same code on the homepage and it works.

I get this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

Comment: just curious, from inside that partial can you check the current user? `<% if user_signed_in? %>`

Comment: Yes. That's something I do inside the same partial, and it works.

Comment: Check the code for that link to make sure that your `:method => :delete` is working because the error is stating your code called it as via `GET`, what won't work

Comment: Have you tried `destroy_user_session_url` instead of `.._path`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is not a problem with it being in a partial. If you look closely, you are setting the `method => delete`, but yet it's calling a `GET` method rather than a `DELETE` method and the `GET` method does not exist.

If i remember correctly you need to have this in your layout.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

Comment: Just about to write the same solution. :)

Comment: Then check your devise initializer. There is a config in there about signout being either GET or DELETE. It should be one of the UN-commented ones.

Comment: I have changed the way it works to GET but I feel like I'm just avoiding the problem a little bit.

Comment: Yea that is not the ideal solution. So if you take this snippet of code out of your partial, you are able to logout just fine?

Comment: I can log out, just not from that partial. Bizzare.

Comment: Check out this answer to see if it helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348421/devise-render-sign-up-in-form-partials-elsewhere-in-code