# Bootstrap Modal and user sign in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

) I am quite new in Ruby so please be indulgent ;-)

I am trying to set up the sign in form within a bootstrap modal but I am keeping the same message errore as it follow : 
NameError in Pages#home

Showing /Users/raphaelbendenoun/code/isrcovoit/app/views/pages/home.html.erb where line #78 raised:

undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<#:0x00000101366738>
Extracted source (around line #78):

```
75:     <h3> id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
76:   </div>
77:   <div class="modal-body">
78:     <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
79:           <div class="inputs">
80:             <%= f.input :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true %>
81:             <%= f.input :password, :required => false %>
Rails.root: /Users/raphaelbendenoun/code/isrcovoit
```

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/pages/home.html.erb:78:in `_app_views_pages_home_html_erb__571334819088820889_2157665500'

Here is my code :

```
 <!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close"  aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3> id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
          <div class="inputs">
            <%= f.input :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true %>
            <%= f.input :password, :required => false %>
            <%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
          </div>
  </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Sign in", :class => 'btn btn-primary', :data => { :dismiss => "modal"} %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing ??
Thx so much for the help, all the tips are welcomed

Comment: You copied code straight from devise?

Comment: This kind of error described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081744/devise-form-within-a-different-controller

Comment: @user2559669, Please follow the Talgat's comment, I guess it will work for you :).